# AngularDart App Layout issue with material-navigation

Tags: html, css, angular, dart, angular-dart

I've been trying to implement a material design site using AngularDart, and I've hit a wall using the angular_components App Layout setup.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to change the look of the nav class="material-navigation" content to match the examples (things like background, text color, and text highlight color).  Currently the text has a grey box surrounding it rather than matching the header color. It doesn't seem like these properties are set in layout.scss, so I'm stumped.  I've made minimal changes to the layout.scss file, which I've posted below. Any insight into what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance :)

[AngularDart Material Nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfruh.png)

```js
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'dart:async';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [
    coreDirectives,
    MaterialIconComponent,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialToggleComponent,
    MaterialListComponent,
    MaterialListItemComponent,
    MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    //Holds modifications for angular_components style sheets. Particularly
    //app_layout, which is *not* a component but a weird grouping of components
    //and styles.
    'main.css',
    'app_component.css',
  ],
  providers: [ClassProvider(NomiService)],
)
...
```

```css
@import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout';

.material-header {
  background-color: $mat-vanilla-red-400; //vs. $mat-indigo-500
}

// A row within the header.
.material-header-row {
  /// Class uses for the title inside of a header.
  .material-header-title {
    left: auto; //vs. $mat-grid * 10;
    height: 36px; //$mat-header-height; //vs. $mat-title-font-size
    font-size: 36px;
    //border: 3px solid green; Use to check work!
    //Used to center text!
    margin-left: 37.5%;
    margin-right: 37.5%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
  }

  .material-navigation{
    border: 3px solid green;
  }

}
```

```html
<header class="material-header shadow">
    <div class="material-header-row">
        <material-button icon class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
            <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
        </material-button>
        <img src="favicon.png" width="30">
        <span class="material-header-title">Nomi</span>
        <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
            <a>Test</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer">
    <material-list>
        <div group>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon ="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon ="star"></material-icon>Star
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon ="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon ="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
    </material-list>
</material-drawer>
```

Comment: Are there any other global styles on the page? Are you using bootstrap or something like it? When I tried to recreate from your example I couldn't repo the error.

Comment: Also general best practice for Sass is to not include Sass file that have side effects. Thus only including ones that have variables and mixins. In this case I would add the layout.css file as one of your styleUrls and have the app_component.css after it in the list, but that is not why you are having errors.